# Angular - ngModel object property from variable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, object, ngmodel

I have the following user object in my application:

```
let user = {name: "John", dob:"1995-10-15", metadata: {}}
```

The `metadata` property of my object is an empty object. On user input, I want to create a new property in the `metadata` object such as:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="user.metadata.childrenNumber" placeholder="Enter number of children"></input>
```

So far so good, everything works as expected. However, the `childrenNumber` property I have stored in an array:

```
let metaDataOptions = ['childrenNumber', 'workStatus', 'education'];
```

How can I reference the property's name I wish to be created from that array? For the case above I tried to do something like this:

```
// i is index from ngFor. i can be 0, 1 or 2
<input [(ngModel)]="user.metadata.metaDataOptions[i]" placeholder="Enter number of children"></input>
```

However, this does not work. How can I achieve the result I desire?

Comment: You can simply use `[(ngModel)]="user.metadata[i]"` just remove `metaDataOptions`

Comment: @RohitSharma I need to store the input of the user in metadata using the names from the `metaDataOptions` and not using numbers.

Comment: Have you tried `user.metadata[metaDataOptions[0]] = 1` to create metaDataOptions key inside  metaData object?

Comment: @lamOptimus Sure! The you can use `[(ngModel)]="user.metadata[metaDataOptions[i]]"`

Comment: @RohitSharma Thank you. This did the trick for me! Although, I can't seem to be able to mark your answer as accepted. Thank you again, take my upvote.

Comment: I have added the answer below. please upvote if that solution works for you!! thank you:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep below object as it is.

```
let user = {name: "John", dob:"1995-10-15", metadata: {}}
let metaDataOptions = ['childrenNumber', 'workStatus', 'education']
```

You can create object property inside the metadata object using below line of code.

```
<input [(ngModel)]="user.metadata[metaDataOptions[i]]" placeholder="Enter number of children"></input>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just let it be

```
let user = {name: "John", dob:"1995-10-15", metadata: { 'childrenNumber' : null}}
```

and then

```
<input [(ngModel)]="user.metadata.childrenNumber" placeholder="Enter number of children"></input>
```

Answer (score 0):

use the index `0`

```
<input [(ngModel)]="user.metadata.metaDataOptions[0]" placeholder="Enter number of children"></input>
```

Comment: Here you can use like: `user.metadata[metaDataOptions[0]]`, but it is limited to the first index only.